# How to cut two intersecting faces?

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

I want to cut the crossing highlighted faces.

[image]

What I want to do is a place for a car tail light.
The idea is for the light to go into that slot.

[image]

What I want is to get new vertex where the red dots are painted.

[image]
Any way of doint that witout doing it manually?
Link to the blend file:
[image]

feedback is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand, why not just extrude/shape the area into a light?  If you have an extra edge just join it to the vertices where you want them or are missing an edge just add a loop cut and use that.  You say you don't want to do it 'manually', what other way is there?  It appears to me that you have a somewhat regular potentially thought-pausing geometry problem

Comment: You can try a Face > Intersect (Knife), then Merge by Distance, but as Jon says, there must be a simpler way